# Facebook Login Django Rest Auth gives "non_field_errors": [ "Incorrect value" ]

Tags: django-rest-framework, facebook-login, django-rest-auth

I had the same issue for google login, but after several changes, I was able to activate it. But for facebook, I am unable to resolve this issue.

```
class GoogleOAuth2AdapterIdToken(GoogleOAuth2Adapter):
    def complete_login(self, request, app, token, **kwargs):
        idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token.token, requests.Request(), app.client_id)
        if idinfo['iss'] not in ['accounts.google.com', 'https://accounts.google.com']:
            raise ValueError('Wrong issuer.')
        extra_data = idinfo
        login = self.get_provider() \
            .sociallogin_from_response(request,
                                       extra_data)
        return login


oauth2_login = OAuth2LoginView.adapter_view(GoogleOAuth2AdapterIdToken)
oauth2_callback = OAuth2CallbackView.adapter_view(GoogleOAuth2AdapterIdToken)


class GoogleLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = GoogleOAuth2AdapterIdToken
    client_class = OAuth2Client

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
        kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
        return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)


class FacebookLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = FacebookOAuth2Adapter
    authentication_classes = []
    client_class = OAuth2Client

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
        kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
        return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
```

this is my views.py where login with google works perfectly fine.

```
Django==3.2.8
django-allauth==0.45.0
django-rest-auth==0.9.5
djangorestframework==3.12.4
```

Following is the error I am getting.

```
HTTP 400 Bad Request
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Incorrect value"
    ]
}
```

I am passing only an access token as an input.

Comment: Was having the same problem for Google. Your included code helped me fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use actual `access_token` from facebook.

It looks like `EAA...`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).